# Is there any material that can prevent silver from tarnishing?

Tags: silver

I am designing a machine that uses paper-thin sheets of silver. I am trying to find a material that can cover the silver to prevent it from tarnishing over time. The material does not have to be abrasive-resistant, as the silver will be placed in a controlled environment. Because of this, appearance does not matter. Perhaps aerogel can work?

Comment: Does the covering need to be abrasion resistant? Chemically inert under specific conditions? Nice looking? Without more information, don't expect a useful answer.

Comment: Something that blocks diffusion of oxygen or sulfur-containing species from the air and doesn't produce any of its own. What about a very thin layer of gold? It can be evaporated or electroplated, but I don't know if the electroplating process is compatible with silver. Now that would be a good question to ask separately. It's also possible that a different but related question could be asked in [Home Improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) just to see if there are existing methods. You could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish#Polyurethane and see what happens.